# How can I get the modified variables of a function to another function?

Tags: php, oop

How can I pass the variables of a function to another function? For example:

```
<?php
class getUserSummaries {

    protected $userNick;

    function func1($userNick) {
        $getUser = file_get_contents('http://example.com/api/' . $userNick . '/summarie/');
        $getUser = json_decode($getUser, true);
        $getUser = $getUser['userid'];
    }

    function func2($var) {
        $getR = file_get_contents('http://example.com/api2/replays/' . $getUser . '/');
        $getR = json_decode($getR, true);
        $getR = $getR[year][month][day][19999];
    }
}
```

I want to pass `$getUser` from the first function (`func1`) to the second function (`func2`).

Comment: if you make it `$this->getUser` it will be visible to func2

Comment: i tried, but it neither work

Comment: wogsland has given a more fleshed out example below

Comment: @DanielMartínMuñoz I've left your last line of logic in place since it constitutes a syntax error, I assume you should have strings around year, month and day but have left that for you to add.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that `$getUser` is undefined in your second function and probably should be **`$var`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is somewhat ambiguous, but I'll answer with the assumption that `func1` will be called and then later `func2` by some external code. And that this could happen multiple times. In this case it makes sense to set a class variable:

```
protected $userId;
```

and add a final line to `func1`:

```
$this->userId = $getUser;
```

and then change the first line of `func2` to

```
$getR = file_get_contents("http://example.com/api2/replays/".$this->userId."/");
```

Please advise if assumptions are not what you're looking for.